# Развернуть пост по клику на заголовок

Tags: jquery

Помогите чуток подправить скрипт.

Вообщем хочу сделать, чтобы по клику на заголовок разворачивался пост. К примеру как на http://pikabu.ru/

Вот раздобыл такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').hide()
    $('.click').click(function(){
        $('.entry').slideToggle("slow");
    })
})
```

Но по клику разворачивается не тот пост на который ты кликнул, а сразу все, что есть на странице.

Посоветуйте как подправить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Недостаточно данных для ответа. 

$('.entry') возвращает всю коллекцию элементов с классом "entry". Вам нужно либо указывать относительный либо абсолютный путь к конкретному посту. 

Если ваша $('.click') находится в непосредственной близости от нужного ".entry" - тогда укажите конкретно, какой entry вам нужен. Есть функции .parent(), .parents(), .next(), prev().

Comment: **html** код еще киньте.

Comment: html код.
                              <div class="click">
  <h2 class="title"></h2>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <p>Facebook Takes Legal Aim at Man Who Claims</p>
</div>

http://s57.radikal.ru/i156/1303/47/fbb5938cdcc0.gif вот как видите, кликаю на один, а открываются сразу все.

Comment: На, нах:

    $('.click').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    })

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').hide()
    $('.click').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    })
})
```

Comment: Не раскрывается почему то по клику.

Comment: @родион-поляков, извините, не увидел кусок `html`, теперь, по сути, продублировал ответ @istem

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.